# Is there any Node js or REST API to create new users in office 365.

Tags: node.js, rest, office365

I have purchased office 365 essentials plan. I have got an admin account. Office provides user interface to add new users under this main admin account.
What I need is I want a Node js or REST API to create users on this account. I have googled well, can't met anything like this. Anyone can provide any samples on this. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: By the looks of it theres no way to create a user by the api, but if they are registered you have the option to add them to groups using the api. As can be seen by here [Microsoft user api](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users)

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 Users are hosted in the background by Azure Active Directory. I believe you should be able to create new accounts for your Office 365 programmatically using the Azure Active Directory Graph API, or probably even better, using the Microsoft Graph API.

Check out the documentation here:
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users

You should be able to get a jump-start using our public samples located here:
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/code-samples-and-sdks

I hope this helps!

Comment: Is that possible single sign on using this microsoft graph.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean here. In order to make the Graph API calls, you will need to have a user token of the Administrator which would be signed into an application you created which would then create the users. Single sign on should be possible for the application you create, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: These links provide REST API's right. What do I provide in the place of 'Authorization : Bearer . Required' in the header .Can you provide a sample with authentication.

Comment: Hi Shawn, I have learned microsoft graph API you have provided. Please provide a sample of code that calls REST API to create users. Because I can't be able create users through Advanced Rest Client application.

Comment: Hi Melvin, Try using the following resources: [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/code-samples-and-sdks) and [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer). Otherwise, please be a little more specific in your needs here. You want me to show you the rest endpoints for creating users?

Comment: Hi Shawn , I tried to create users with the below REST API url :                       POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
  "userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value@onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password-value"
  }
}  . But it resulted Status: 401: Unauthorized
can you explain how can I set the Authorization header. Please provide a javascript sample(node js)